# Regular expression to match date format MM/dd/yyyy and (or) M/d/yyyy

Tags: java, string, date, datetime, java-7

I need to find a regex that will match both date formats:

```
MM/dd/yyyy and M/d/yyyy
ex. 01/31/2022, 1/1/2022, 12/13/2022, 12/1/2022
```

So far I tried

```
^(1[0-2]|0[1-9])/(3[01]|[12][0-9]|0[1-9]{1}$)/[0-9]{4}$
```

Which seems to be the closes to what I need, but it's still not perfect. I am on Java 7 and I need to validate user's input, thus I need to verify if they gave me correct date format. For example, if they enter `13/1/2022`, then `SimpleDateFormat` translates this to `Sun Jan 01 00:00:00 CET 2023`.

Comment: Don’t use a regex for date format validation. Use `LocalDate` and a `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: Are you wanting to disallow `2/04/2023` and `03/5/2023`? Asking because they neither seem to be `MM/dd/yyyy` nor `M/d/yyyy`.

Comment: In which way not perfect? (Not that the perfect exists …)

Comment: I want to allow 1/1/2022, 01/01/2022 but disallow 13/01/2022 as there is no month number 13

Comment: @Lenny A regex solution for this can be too complex. I strongly recommend you use the Date-Time API for the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am on Java 7 and I need to validate user's input thus I need to
> verify if they gave me correct date format.

For Java 8+, I recommend [this answer by Alexander Ivanchenko](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74632659/10819573). With Java 6 or 7, you can still use that answer with the help of [ThreeTen Backport](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) library which backports `java.time` API to Java 6 and 7.

However, if you do not want to use the ThreeTen-Backport library and want to stick to Java standard library, you can use [`DateFormat#setLenient(boolean)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient(boolean)) with `false` as the value.

**Demo**:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yyyy");
        sdf.setLenient(false);
        String[] arr = { "01/31/2022", "1/1/2022", "12/13/2022", "12/1/2022", "13/01/2022" };

        for (String s : arr) {
            try {
                System.out.println("==================");
                sdf.parse(s);
                System.out.println(s + " is a valid date");
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());

                // Recommended so that the caller can handle the exception appropriately
                // throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid date");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
==================
01/31/2022 is a valid date
==================
1/1/2022 is a valid date
==================
12/13/2022 is a valid date
==================
12/1/2022 is a valid date
==================
Unparseable date: "13/01/2022"
```

Comment: IDE tells me that SimpleDateFormat does not have method setLenient()

Comment: @Lenny This method has been there since the first release of `SimpleDateFormat`. Actually, this method is available to `SimpleDateFormat` via its superclass,`DateFormat`. I have added the [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient(boolean)) in the answer. Please make sure you have imported `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: You are right - I checked that SimpleDateFormat extends DateFormat and in that super class I can see setLenient() method. I must have some problems with my IDE.

Answer (score 4):

You can successfully parse all specified dates using the same pattern `"M/d/yyyy"`, where `M` and `d` denotes the **minimal** expected number of digits for the Month and the Day of the month, respectively.

There's no need to use regular expressions.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/yyyy");
System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("01/31/2022", formatter));
System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("1/1/2022", formatter));
System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("12/13/2022", formatter));
System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("12/1/2022", formatter));
```

*Output:*

```
2022-01-31
2022-01-01
2022-12-13
2022-12-01
```

To simulate Java 8 Time API features without the updating JDK version, you can add [*ThreeTen Backport*](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) library to your project and utilize it's implementations of [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) and [`LocalDate`](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/LocalDate.html) with Java 7 (credits to *@Ole V.V.* for this idea).

Comment: I cannot user DateTimeFormater as I need to verify if user entered correct date format. With the solution above user can enter 13/1/2022 and it will be translated to ```Sun Jan 01 00:00:00 CET 2023``` (and I am on Java 7)

Comment: Not so, @Lenny. That gives `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '13/1/2022' could not be parsed: Invalid value for MonthOfYear (valid values 1 - 12): 13` (and please enjoy the explanatory exception message). You will want to use `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/yyyy").withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT)` for still stricter validation, though. Were you trying `M/d/yyyy` with `SimpleDateFormat`?? Don’t!! You will get nothing but trouble from using that class.

Comment: If you're using Java 7 (*which was released more than **10** years ago*) you can use neither `DateTimeFormatter`, no `LocalDate` because they were introduced with Java 8. It is impossible to caver all cases of invalid dates with regular expressions, how would you validate something like `02.29.2020` ? You could cut off some scenarios using regex, but there would be no guarantee that the input is correct. So you're using `java.util.Date`?

Comment: For Java 7 the simplest and also the most convenient solution is to use [ThreeTen Backport](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of java.time to Java 6 and 7. Just tried it with Java 7 and the code from this answer, it works flawlessly. Only the exception class is in a different package: `org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '13/1/2022' could not be parsed: Invalid value for MonthOfYear (valid values 1 - 12): 13`, that’s all. @AlexanderIvanchenko